# Search the name of the logged user

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, mysqli

Well I've got a website, in the header of this website I've got two links, one to login and another one to register. I want that, when the user is logged in, those two links disappear, so i can have one saying "Hello " followed by a link to the control panel. like "Hello . . The thing is that it isn't searching the name of the user. It just doesn't show the name. The user is logged with the email and password, and the function `usuarioEstaLogado()` is the one that confirm the user is logged. Here's the codes:

```
   function nomeUsuario($conexao){
        $usuarios = array();
        $query = "select nome from usuarios where email = '{$mail}'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
        while($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
            array_push($usuarios, $usuario);
        }
        return $usuarios;
    }


<?php
session_start();
function usuarioEstaLogado() {
    return isset($_SESSION["usuario_logado"]);
}

<div class="container container-twelve">

        <header>
            <div class="twelve columns top remove-bottom">
                <div class="three columns offset-by-nine">
                    <?php 
                        if(usuarioEstaLogado()){
                            $usr = nomeUsuario($conexao);
                            echo" <p>Ola " . $usr['nome'];
                            "<a href='admin'> Painel de Controle</a></p>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    <p><a href="cadastro.php">Cadastre-se</a> | 
                    <a href="login.php">Login <span class="icon-user"></span></a></p>
                </div>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: When the user is logged it don't change the header with his name and the link to access control panel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your top function

```
    $query = "select nome from usuarios where email = '{$mail}'";
```

`$mail` is undefined, you haven't pulled it from global, nor passed it to the `nomeUsario` function, so that query probably doesn't return anything.

Your nome function should probably accept an email. Additionally, you probably want the first match in the db, not all of them, like:

```
function nomeUsuario($conexao, $mail) {
    $query = "select nome from usuarios where email = '{$mail}'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
    if ($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        return $usuario;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and when you call it, you need the email address, which I am *guessing* is in the `$_SESSION`?

```
$usr = nomeUsuario($conexao,$_SESSION['usuario_email']); //or whatever the name may be :-)
echo" <p>Ola " . $usr['nome'];
```

Comment: So how could i make it search from the email the user logged in ?

Comment: Weird, but now the page is driving me this : 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/u374984363/public_html/newcars/functions.php on line 179, i don't even have a variable $end in the functions...

Comment: That error is what you get when you nested code blocks wrong – count your opening and closing curly braces, most likely they don’t match.

Comment: It was alright but the problem persisted... I guess the file was too big, so i just made a funtions2.php and it worked alright. Thank you!